# Using CLI to run Python script on inputs to generate outputs

Tags: python, csv, command-line-interface

I am having trouble understanding how to use a CLI command to run a Python script on input file parameters to generate output files. From what I understand, `analysis.py` is the python script and `-s` and `-p` are the variable names that will contain the csv data from `Sales.csv` and `Products.csv` respectively. In the `analysis.py`, How would I accept the two CSVs stored in `-s` and `-p`, and then create an output called `SalesReport.csv`? Would I create a blank csv file titled `SalesReport.csv` and then write the analyzed data to the file? Or would the command-line create a `SalesReport.csv` file for me using data stored in a sales-report variable.

```
python analysis.py -s Sales.csv -p Products.csv --sales-report=SalesReport.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `argparse.ArgumentParser` class to create a parser like so:

```py
import sys
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sales')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--products')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--sales-report')
    return parser.parse_args(), parser


def main():
    args, parser = parse_args()

    # did user user run the script without giving any args?
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        parser.print_help()
        return

    sales_path = args.sales
    products_path = args.products
    report_path = args.sales_report

    print('sales', sales_path)
    print('products', products_path)
    print('report', report_path)

    # generate report somehow
    report = []
    with open(sales_path) as sales_file, open(products_path) as products_file:
        # here I just combine both files
        report.extend(sales_file.readlines())
        report.extend(products_file.readlines())

    # save the report
    with open(report_path, 'w') as report_file:
        report_file.writelines(report)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then run it:

```
> python analysis.py -s Sales.csv -p Products.csv --sales-report SalesReport.csv
```

How you generate the report is up to you. Here I've just combined both files.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response abdusco. I'm still a little confused. When assigning args.sales_report to sales_report, wouldn't you want to use args.sales instead? And would report_file be assigned to args.sales-report?

Comment: Oh sorry, just realized that you edited it. Nevermind! Appreciate the help

Comment: Ah ok, let me know if you need any help

Comment: Question, how would I be able to analyze the data returned from argparse? I tried assigning sales_file.readlines() and products_file.readlines() to variables and then working with those but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean my analysis? The program wont magically create a report for you.

Comment: Nevermind, just got it to work. I appreciate the response.